# about istringstream and >>operator

Tags: c++, istringstream

```
string str = "0.000 0.005 0.001";
istringstream s(str);
string sub;
while (s)
{
    s >> sub;
    cout << sub << endl;
}
```

That is my code, I just want to output every number in `str`, but I get the last number twice. I know there are many better ways to implement it, but I want to know what is wrong with this code.Do I get something wrong on `operator>>`?

Comment: That code does not output every number twice, it only outputs the *last* number twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
while (s >> sub)
{
    cout << sub << endl;
}
```

instead. In your code you end up "eating" the end of stream, so `s >> sub` fails, and `sub` remains unchanged with the last good read (i.e. last number), therefore you end up displaying it twice.

Related: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)